# What is the boundary of the set $\{ x : dist (x ,\partial \Omega) > \alpha \}$ for a domain $\Omega$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ is a bounded open domain in $\mathbb R ^n$, and $\alpha \geq 0$ a real number, and consider the set $ E_\alpha = \{ x \in \Omega : \text{dist}(x , \partial \Omega) > \alpha\}  $, which $\text{dist}$ is the usual distance between a point and a set. What is the boundary of $E_\alpha$?

In particular I want to know what conditions  should be imposed on $\Omega$ to ensure that  $ \partial E_\alpha  =  \{ x \in \Omega : \text{dist}(x , \partial \Omega) = \alpha\}  $?

What is situation with geometric measure theoretic boundary (the reduced boundary) $\partial ^ \ast \{ x \in \Omega : \text{dist}(x , \partial \Omega) \}$?

Revision from comments: If $\Omega$ isn't convex, there are simple counterexamples, thus let $\Omega$ be convex. Also, for larger values of $\alpha$,  ($\alpha > \text{diam} (\Omega)$ for instance). Thus the revised version is: 
Let $\Omega$ is a bounded and convex open domain in $\mathbb R ^n$, and $\alpha \geq 0$ a real number, $\alpha$ is smaller than some $\varepsilon > 0$, what (regularity) assumptions should imposed on $\Omega$ and $\partial \Omega$ to ensure that   $\partial \{ x \in \Omega : \text{dist}(x , \partial \Omega) > \alpha\} = \{ x \in \Omega : \text{dist}(x , \partial \Omega) = \alpha\}$?

Comment: It can't just be regularity conditions.  If $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is the annulus $1 < |x| < 2$ and $\alpha = 1$, then $0 \notin \partial E_\alpha$ even though $\mathrm{dist}(0, \partial \Omega) = \alpha$.

Comment: @StanleySnelson: But it's the distance to $\partial \Omega$, not to $\bar{\Omega}$.  So we would apparently need $\partial \Omega$ to be convex, which seems extremely restrictive.  In fact, come to think of it, the desired statement is not satisfied by the unit ball when $\alpha = 1$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I misread the question.

Comment: In fact, as to the first question, there are *no* nontrivial sets $\Omega$ that satisfy this conclusion for all $\alpha$.  Since $\bar{\Omega}$ is compact and distance to a closed set is continuous, let $\alpha = \max_{x \in \bar\Omega} \mathrm{dist}(x, \partial \Omega)$; since $\bar\Omega$ has nonempty interior, we have $\alpha > 0$.  Then $E_\alpha$ is disjoint from $\Omega$ by construction of $\alpha$, and hence so is $\partial E_\alpha$ (since $\Omega$ is open).  But the maximum above is attained at some point of $\Omega$.

Comment: So is that really what you meant to ask?

Comment: @NateEldredge I think of an open and convex domain $\Omega$, and I want to know what can be said about boundary of $E_\alpha$ for small values of $\alpha$. The condition that $\partial \Omega$ to be convex is, as you said, extremely restrictive, even the boundary of unit circle is not convex. I want to know, for example, is there any regularity conditions to be imposed on $\Omega$ ($\Omega$ image of a $C^1$ function, or a Lipschitz, etc.) to be ensure that $ \partial E_\alpha =  \{ x \in \Omega : \text{dist}(x , \partial \Omega) = \alpha\}$ for $\alpha$ very very small?

Comment: In particular is it true that $\partial E_\alpha =  \{ x \in \Omega : \text{dist}(x , \partial \Omega) = \alpha\}$, for $\Omega$ a (connected) Lipschitz domain, and $\alpha$ very small?

Comment: Maybe some additional assumptions about regularity of $\partial \Omega$ is required?